# Can I retrieve metadata in Adobe Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, metadata

I'm about to make a flash AS3 program that gets a jpg and displays it along with the metadata. I have no clue on how I can retrieve the metadata or is it even possible? How should I do it?

Comment: Are you talking about EXIF? If so try http://code.google.com/p/exif-as3/